# How can I show a modal that warns 10 seconds before the session ends?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a project in Angular where the session expires at the end of 60 minutes as the known token is invalidated.
Currently I have a JWT interceptor that when it detects the invalidated token takes me to the login page.
I would like to implement a modal window in which the user is notified of the imminent session termination.
How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get a token from the server, you can set a timer for the notification modal. The JWT have an exp field that saving data when the token have been expired,so your solution will looks like this:

```
setExpiredTimer(): void {
    this.authService.token$
      .pipe(
        switchMap(({ exp }) => timer(Number(new Date(exp) - 10000)))
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.showNotificationModal());
  }
```

Comment: dow i take exp value? In my this.authFacade.accessToken$  i have only token.

Comment: @Man24 https://jwt.io/ jwt is an encoded Javascript object. You can parse it with some library, for example, that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode

Comment: thanks you, but where i have to put this function? 
When user are allow login?

Comment: @Man24 .pipe(
        map((token: string) => parseJWT(token)),
        switchMap(({ exp }) => timer(Number(new Date(exp) - 10000)))
      )